# For loop counter of IP address segment lengths not counting last segment

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, counter

Please enter an IP address 1012.321.32.21
segmentLength of segment # 1 is 4
segmentLength of segment # 2 is 3
segmentLength of segment # 3 is 2
segmentCount is 4

My Python program is not counting the segment length of the last segment, which in this case is 2. Why is that?

```
address = input("Please enter an IP address ")

segmentCount = 0
segmentLength = 0

for char in address:
    if char in "0123456789":
        segmentLength += 1

elif char not in "0123456789":
    segmentCount += 1
    print("segmentLength of segment #", segmentCount, "is   {}".format(segmentLength))
    segmentLength = 0


#Adding 1 to segmentCount to account for segment after last dot.
print("segmentCount is {}".format(segmentCount + 1))
```

Expected result:
Please enter an IP address 1012.321.32.21
segmentLength of segment # 1 is 4
segmentLength of segment # 2 is 3
segmentLength of segment # 3 is 2
segmentLength of segment # 4 is 2
segmentCount is 4

Actual result:
Please enter an IP address 1012.321.32.21
segmentLength of segment # 1 is 4
segmentLength of segment # 2 is 3
segmentLength of segment # 3 is 2
segmentCount is 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing on the character not in your list of numbers.  The end of the list does not enter the for loop to reach the last print.

```
address = input("Please enter an IP address ")

segmentCount = 1
segmentLength = 0

for char in address:
    if char in "0123456789":
        segmentLength += 1

    elif char not in "0123456789":

        print("segmentLength of segment #", segmentCount, "is   {}".format(segmentLength))
        segmentCount += 1
        segmentLength = 0


#NO LONGER-- Adding 1 to segmentCount to account for segment after last dot.
print("segmentLength of segment #", segmentCount, "is   {}".format(segmentLength))
print("segmentCount is {}".format(segmentCount ))
```

Now this isn't the best code, as you wouldn't want to have the additional print statement, but it should illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: I used, one by one, the commenting out of the 2 segment length print statements to see what you mean.  That helps a lot!  Thank you so much for your help!